# Continuity of supremum and infimum

Tags: reference-request, continuity

I cannot find a proof of this theorem, but I have a strong feeling that it is true. Can someone remind me where to find it (or if I am confused and it is false)?

Let $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ be a continuous function, where $X\subset \mathbb R^n, Y\subset \mathbb R^m$ are compact sets.

Then the functions $g(x) = \sup_y f(x,y)$ and $h(x) = \inf_y f(x,y)$ are also continuous.

**Edit:** Can you provide a textbook reference, instead of a website? Thanks

Comment: This website contains your answer and much more: https://williewong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/continuity-of-the-infimum/

Comment: @CMonsour Thanks.

Comment: Is there a textbook reference for this? Thanks in advance..